# xslt import/include 2 files with the same template

Tags: xslt, import, include, rules, operator-precedence

I've got an interesting question on XSLT import/include.

I have 2 XSLT files with the same rule.

Receipt XSLT: (is run by itself)

```
<xsl:template match="Booking" mode="extraStyle">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/receipt.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</xsl:template>
```

EmailCommon XSLT: (serves as template library for Email docs, isn't run by itself)

```
 <xsl:template match="Booking" mode="extraStyle">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/email.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
 </xsl:template>
```

So that depending on the document type I insert correct CSS files.

What I'm trying to do is to include these two documents into yet another XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" 
version="1.0">

<xsl:include href="receipt.xsl"/>
<xsl:include href="email.xsl"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Nevertheless, because the rules are the same in both included stylesheets it boils down to the Last-in-first rule and I end up only including email.css.

I was wondering if something smart could be done in this case?

The only thing I was thinking is to using different mode, but then it wouldn't be as intuitive, rather then accumalate the code of all identical rules. Don't know how and whether at all it could be done in XSLT.

Thanks for help!

P.S. Sorry, I'm really trying to understand the formating rules on this site, but I simply can't :( gggrrr

Comment: You must define the desired behavior more closely. Under which circumstances do you want the one template to run, and under which circumstances the other?

Comment: @Tomalak, the thing is that in the stylesheet where I include both receipt.xsl and email.xsl (that's just a template library) I want both templates to be executed. But according to the Last-in-first rule, the same template is executed for the latest included stylesheet, e.i. for email.xsl.

I was wondering if there is a smart way to make sure both templates from receipt.xsl and email.xsl can be executed. Or will I need to use different mode?

Does it make sense?

Comment: What purpose does the 'mode' attribute serve in the existing code; that is why are both templates defined with mode='extraStyle'; and how are they invoked?

Answer (score 2):

I think making the template modes different is your best option.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" 
>

  <xsl:include href="receipt.xsl"/>
  <xsl:include href="email.xsl"/>

  <xsl:template match="Booking">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="extraStyleReceipt" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="extraStyleEmail" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```